# Production build is missing a piece of template

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vite

As the problem states, the `router-view` is not showing up within the `vite preview`, however it does show up when running `vite`. I need to have it work in the preview, since that is also the one that shows up on production. I do make sure to also run the build before I run `vite preview`, however this has had no use so far.

nginx.conf

```
location / {
    gzip off;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

I tried out the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` from another post, which did not seem to work in my case.

router.js

```js
const history = createWebHistory();

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
  },
];

const router = new createRouter({
  history: history,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import "./index.css";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <base-layout>
      <template v-slot:header>
        <Header/>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <Sidebar/>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:footer>
        <Footer/>
      </template>
  </base-layout>
</template>
```

Of course this also has the components of the header, footer and sidebar and the v-slot is where the header, content and footer are slotted in place.

My question in this all is, how can I configure Vite and Vue 3.x to show the `router-view` whenever I use `vite preview`?

Comment: Do the header/footer show but the default doesn't? Or there is nothing at all? Could maybe try to remove `v-slot:default` because it's already the default behavior (if not specified). Also, did you inspect with the browser + vue devtools to see the difference between the `dev` and the `preview` build? Why do you share the NGINX configuration? Is it relevant here? You don't try it locally on your machine (`build` + `preview`)?

Comment: @kissu the header/footer show, but the default doesn't yes. I did inspect the browser with the `dev` and `preview` build and it seems like `router-view` doesn't show up on `preview` but it does with `dev`, so basically the content is missing with the inspector. NGINX is configured mainly to automate https, I guess NGINX is not relevant for this topic anymore, I was confused when I posted the question, however it might just have to do with the router as a whole that isn't working on `preview`

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure of the issue. I've tried reproducing your issue in [this repo](https://github.com/kissu/router-view-disappearing) without any success. Mind telling me what I'm missing when compared to your code snippets?

Comment: @kissu there is no difference except that you're running eslint and I'm using jest, I don't think that'd be the problem honestly- but for me the `vite preview` just does not input the dashboard inside the `router-view`

Comment: @kissu correction* I'm using jest with babel

Comment: Yeah, Jest will not be breaking anything here since it's not even touching to the code itself. Do you have a public repo for your project that we could look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure how even this was working in `dev` mode but it should not work at all.

So, I've added ESlint + Prettier to clean the whole project a bit + bring up some warning/errors. You can check it per-file, but places like the `vite.config.js` are having 2 interesting errors (`process.env.NODE_ENV` is a webpack thing, not [a Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables-and-modes) one for example).

Then, I've tried to isolate the views/components to find out what was the issue. Turned out `Carousel.vue` was using some hacky stuff. Also, the pagination pages were not really working initially.

I saw that you've installed [vue3-carousel](https://github.com/ismail9k/vue3-carousel) but were not actually using it. Hence, I've implemented a quick and simple carousel looking at the other one that you've got.

Here is the actual code of my freshly created `WorkingCarousel.vue`

```html
<template>
  <section class="flex">
    <carousel :items-to-show="2.5" :ref="carouselRef">
      <slide v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <div class="item-size">
          <img :src="item.imageUrl" />
          <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
    <div class="pagination">
      <button @click="previousSlide">prev</button>
      <button @click="nextSlide" style="margin-left: 1rem">next</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import 'vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css'
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue3-carousel'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Carousel,
    Slide,
  },
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    carouselRef: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      required: true,
    },
    fallbackImgSrc: {
      type: String,
      default: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random',
    },
    fallbackImgTitle: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Avatar',
    },
  },
  computed: {
    fallbackImgAlt() {
      return this.fallbackImgTitle
    },
  },
  methods: {
    nextSlide() {
      this.$refs[this.carouselRef].next()
    },
    previousSlide() {
      this.$refs[this.carouselRef].prev()
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.pagination {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.item-size img {
  height: 8rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
```

And here is the actual result of the working carousel, this is working totally fine while checking the production build (`preview` script) and using more usual Vue patterns.

Comment: found out there just was an unused :ref on the other carousel... xD